# ですよ in Kansai-ben

Tags: sentence-final-particles, kansai-ben

What does the sentencing ending particle ですよ become in Kansai-ben?

Answer (score 5):

In Kansai-ben ですよ can, according to [Ikue Shingu's Kansai Grammar Index](http://www.kansaiben.com/9.Index/2index.html), become

- どすえ
- どっせ
- だっせ
- でっせ

but I would consider it as *raw* Kansai-ben. You almost never hear it (I never did) and it can stay as ですよ. Kansai-ben is also the intonation, choice of words and in other parts of the sentence than the end copula.

だよ on the other hand becomes in the most general way やで.

Comment: +1 for `やで`.  I never heard any of those other four either.

Comment: でっせ sounds masculine and is very often heard in Osaka, while どすえ sounds feminine and is only used in Kyoto. I don't think I've ever heard　どっせ or だっせ.

Comment: How does one go about perceiving this supposed masculinity or femininity of sound, anyway? o_O

Comment: @KarlKnechtel-san, Are you talking to me?